# How to track my epic badge?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

I can't seem to figure out how to track the epic badge. On my user profile page at Stack Overflow, I click on the gear icon to `Select your next badge` - I'm expecting to find the epic badge there, but I don't see it. I have a handful of 200+ days under my belt so I know I'm partially the way there.

[image]

Comment: There are two parts of the profile where you can track badges. Only tag badges can be tracked in the left side. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viMIO.png)